# Pushing updates on a range from source to target. only returning blanks

Tags: vba, excel

The code below is only returning blanks in the target workbook, but the source workbook has values. I believe it's in the line starting in "Wkb.Worksheets....". Any pointers much appreciated.

```
Sub UpdateAdminBook()

Dim wbSrc As Workbook
Set wbSrc = ActiveWorkbook
Dim MyPath          As String
Dim MyFile          As String
Dim Wkb             As Workbook
Dim Cnt             As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

MyPath = "T:\4 - Operating\Tribute at Heritage Village - Manassas VA 1\Community Operations\Department Spend Down Sheets\" 'change the path accordingly

If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"

MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "Administration.xlsx")

Cnt = 0
Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    Cnt = Cnt + 1
    Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFile)
    Wkb.Worksheets("Administration").Range("D18:D37").Value = wbSrc.Sheets("Administration").Range("D18:D37") 'change the new value accordingly
    Wkb.Close savechanges:=True
    MyFile = Dir
Loop

If Cnt > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Completed...", vbExclamation
Else
    MsgBox "No files were found!", vbExclamation
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Looks OK to me.  Are you sure you're picking up the correct source workbook - do you have other workbooks open?  Also, your path to `Dir()` has no wildcards, so it's not clear why you need the loop.

Comment: The MyPath is the target and wbSrc is the source (from where I'm initiating the macro). Is this correct?

Comment: You are missing the .value after range

Comment: Wkb.Worksheets("Administration").Range("D18:D37").Value = wbSrc.Sheets("Administration").Range("D18:D37").Value

Comment: `.Value` is the default property of Range - I would expect that not to be the problem...

Comment: Thank you @VBAPete !!! You just made my life so much easier.

Comment: my pleasure @JuanSebastianMedina

Comment: @TimWilliams I didn't think it was needed either, but when I tested it the values did not copy.

Comment: @VBAPete - fair enough.  That's not what i would have expected.